# Escaping bracket in PHP {}

Tags: php, html

I am getting input from a HTML form in this format: `template = ... {name} ... {amount} ....{time}...` the dots represent the other message. I want to save that whole string message in a database but escape the brackets {} in the string how do I go about that? Any one? Sample code from a post form:

```
 $value = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['template']);
```

Comment: What is the output of the $value??

Comment: It still has  the brackets {}...

Comment: why do you need that? `MySQL` doesn't treat brackets like something special.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use string replace while entering the data to database :

```
$value = str_replace("{","++",$value);
$value = str_replace("}","--",$value);
```

And again replace them when getting the value out of database :

```
$value = str_replace("++","{",$value);
$value = str_replace("--","}",$value);
```

Answer (score 0):

I not understand your question completely. But below one will help you

```
$search = array ('{','}');
$replace = array ('','');
$template = str_replace($search, $replace, "{name}{amount}{product}");
echo $template;
```

OUTPUT:

```
nameamountproduct
```